# Get last days of previous months

Tags: php, arrays

```
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
{

 $monthArr[] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('2011-10-31'. -1*$i.' month'));

 }
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2011-10-31
    [1] => 2011-10-01    //Here should be 2011-09-30
    [2] => 2011-08-31
    [3] => 2011-07-31
)
```

I would like the output like the following, Thanks!

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2011-10-31
    [1] => 2011-09-30
    [2] => 2011-08-31
    [3] => 2011-07-31
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$days_past = 0;    
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {
    $monthArr[] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('2011-10-31 '.$days_past.' days'));
    $days_past -= cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 10 - $i, 2011);
}
```

- 0 days
- 31 days
- 61 days
  etc.

Comment: This is the proper way to do it. Others are just work around even if they have worked.

Comment: @aartist: Please tell me why my solution is not "the proper way to do it".

Answer (score 6):

```
strtotime('2011-10-31 -1 month');
```

This equates to 2011-09-31 which doesn't exist and hence it gets changed to the day after 2011-09-30 which is 2011-10-01.

Rather than loop through the last day of the month (which is variable), try looping through the first day of the month and then calculating the last day of that month, i.e.

```
date( 'Y-m-t', strtotime('2011-10-01 '. -1*$i .' month') );
```

EDIT: the "t" flag for the date() function returns the last day of the month.

Comment: Yes, but there are two things: 1) `$1` is not valid variable name (in this case it should be `$i`, I believe), 2) it should be mentioned that `t` in `date()` parameter is the clue that solves the problem by returning number of days for a given month.

Comment: @Tadeck Good spot. Have updated post following your suggestion and to fix the typo ;-)

Comment: @Tadeck Thanks, perfect SO behaviour! Now I'm just waiting for the OP to mark my response as the answer...

Comment: This might yield the correct result, but it's not obvious what this does since most people probably won't know the 't' flag. My example with 'last day of' should be clear without the need for comments.

Comment: @Bluewind Yes, that's a fair point. I use the "t" flag so often it feels very natural to me now and I forget it's not very obvious!

Answer (score 2):

```
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {
    $monthArr[] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('last day of 2011-10-31 '. -1*$i.' month'));
}
```

instead of '2011-10-31' you can also write 'today' for the current month.

Example output:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "2011-10-31 00:00:00"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "2011-09-30 00:00:00"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "2011-08-31 00:00:00"
  [3]=>
  string(19) "2011-07-31 00:00:00"
  [4]=>
  string(19) "2011-06-30 00:00:00"
  [5]=>
  string(19) "2011-05-31 00:00:00"
  [6]=>
  string(19) "2011-04-30 00:00:00"
  [7]=>
  string(19) "2011-03-31 00:00:00"
  [8]=>
  string(19) "2011-02-28 00:00:00"
  [9]=>
  string(19) "2011-01-31 00:00:00"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has `DateTime` class available which should be used instead of `date` and `strtotime` functions because you can imply what time zone to use, therefore you can be "safe" when it comes to DST and many other things.

How to use it to solve your problem:

```
$date = '2011-11-30'; // our date that we deal with 

$tz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');

// create new DateTime object specifying the format and the date we create from as well as the time zone we're in
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date, $tz);

// let's substract 1 month from current DateTime object     
$sub = $dt->sub(new DateInterval('P1M')); // P stands for PERIOD, 1 stands for ONE and M stands for MONTH - so it means we're substracting period of 1 month 

// output the new date 

echo $sub->format('Y-m-d);
```

Comment: This fails to find the really last day of the month. You just subtract one month, but if you start at 30 you will never hit 31 (for months with 31 days).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the mktime() function:

https://www.php.net/mktime

```
// I'm assuming today's date here, but adjust accordingly
$start_day   = date('j');
$start_month = date('n');
$start_year  = date('Y');
for($i=0; $i<4; $i++)
{
    $monthArr[] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(1, 1, 1, $start_day, $start_month - $i, $start_year));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

does this help:

```
for($i = 0, $j=11; $i < 4; $i++) {

    echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day", strtotime(date("Y-$j-01"))));
    echo "<br />";
    $j--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the PHP DateTime class too.
Every thing become easy and simple when use it.

```
// Get last day of previous month
$date = new DateTime();
$dayOfMonth = $date->format('j');
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P' . $dayOfMonth . 'D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

if you just want to get the last of a month, why not just simply use an array, as only the February need tack care, other months have a fixed last day.

when you want to get a week start date and end date, you may need DateTime.